# not being able to write the last row into csv

Tags: python, csv, export

My parent dataset contains 1 tweet in each row. I am cleaning tweets and extracting feature words from the tweets and exporting it to csv. I am being able to export all but one last row. I am using the follwoing piece of code:

```
#Read the tweets one by one and process it
fp = open('C:/Twitter_crawl/tweetDB4_import.csv', 'r')


st = open('C:/Twitter_crawl/stopwords.txt', 'r')
stopWords = getStopWordList('C:/Twitter_crawl/stopwords.txt')

for line in fp.readlines():
    a = csv.writer(open('feature_vector.csv', 'a'))
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
    a.writerow(featureVector)
    print (featureVector)
#end loop
fp.close()
```

Can anyone please help me out with the looping so that the last row also gets exported?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not closing a file might leave many other lines not written as well. Last one is just easy target to notice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file feature_vector.csv.  You are actually opening it every time through the loop, which is bad.  Open it once before the loop and close it once afterward.

Also the variable st is not used.

Answer (score 0):

As in Paul Cornelius' answer - your problem is that you are opening your .csv file every time you go round the loop, but not closing it.

It is safer, with file operations, to use the `with open('file', 'r') as openfile:` construct, because this takes care of closing the file again for you, even if an exception happens and the script terminates early.

Something like this:

```
st = open('C:/Twitter_crawl/stopwords.txt', 'r')
stopWords = getStopWordList('C:/Twitter_crawl/stopwords.txt')

with open('C:/Twitter_crawl/tweetDB4_import.csv', 'r') as fp:
    with open('feature_vector.csv', 'a') as op:
        a = csv.writer(op)
        for line in fp.readlines():
            processedTweet = processTweet(line)
            featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
            a.writerow(featureVector)
            print (featureVector)
        #end loop
```

I've left the `stopwords` lines in, even though they are not used....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not close your target file.
Perhaps you should use something like:

```
with open('feature_vector.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
```